# How to use cert and key file with Python Requests on client side?

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I have a homework assignment, where I have to communicate with a server. I'm at the last task, but I can't get it to work. The task is the following:

- Connect to http://[Server IP] and download cert.php and key.php files.
- After that, use these files to GET https://[Server IP].
- If the HTTPS request is successful, the server will reply with the unique flag. (hw's solution)

I can download the files no problem, but when I try to use them, I get errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1122)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='152.66.249.144', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1122)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\HF\hf_script.py", line 195, in <module>
    final_conn = requests.get(url_https,
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='152.66.249.144', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1122)')))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have also tried saving the files with `.pem` extension, I don't even know if that makes sense, but didn't work. Furthermore I have tried to use `ssl` and creating an unverified context, but it says `Cannot find reference '_create_unverified_context' in 'ssl.pyi'`

Here's the code I work with:

```
# Creating request with session cookie
s = requests.session()
r = s.post(url, data=data)

# Downloading the cert
cert = s.get(cert_url)
open('cert.php', 'wb').write(cert.content)

# Downloading the key
key = s.get(key_url)
open('key.php', 'wb').write(key.content)

final_conn = requests.get(url_https,
                          cert=('C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/HF/cert.php',
                                'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/HF/key.php'))
print(final_conn.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got it. I doubt anyone will use this, but the cert and key I used was fine, the pbroblem was, the server itself was using a self-signed certificate, and I had to establish the connection anyway. The solution that worked for me:

```
final_conn = requests.get(url_https,
                          cert=('C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/HF/cert.php',
                                'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/HF/key.php'),
                          verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify = false make client authentication void.
If both client and server are using self signed certificates created with same domain name it is giving error for ssl certificate. If you want to use certificates both self signed just change the name(fqdn) or ip address while creating certificates.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).